# Convert JSON String into variables to echo out

Tags: php, foreach, json

I have the following JSON string:

```
[{\"index\":0,\"date\":\" 20120030\",\"title\":\"afsa\"}]
```

And I need to get out the contents into a variable foreach one.

This is how it is picked up so far...

```
 $json_data_string = $_POST['hidden_event']; // sanitize however
 $array_data = json_decode($json_data_string);

 echo $json_data_string;
```

I need to be able to echo each out. for example:

```
 foreach {
   echo $date;
   echo $title;
 }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: if u want to do that using jquery ajax and php i will help u out little..

Comment: Great. I just need the data into a variable for each statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you want to use this using jquery you will do like this:-

```
var recordList = [{\"index\":0,\"date\":\" 20120030\",\"title\":\"afsa\"}]

jQuery.each(recordList, function()
{
    alert(this.Name); // For example
    alert(this.date); // For example
});
```

or like this:-

```
      $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: URL,
                          cache:false,
                          data: values,
                          dataType:'json',
                          success: function(json)
           {
                                var date = json.date;
                                alert(date);
                                }       // end success function
                        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($array_data as $data) {
  echo $data->date, PHP_EOL;
  echo $data->title, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: try changing the lines to `echo $data->date . "\n";` and `echo $data->title . "\n";`

Comment: h2ooooooo is right about -> instead of => (i corrected my typo) but you should prefer PHP_EOL over "\n"

Comment: @mathroc `PHP_EOL` is useful for log files or command line integration, but in this case where you're outputting it to the user, it wouldn't make a difference, as no matter whether you use `\n` or `\r\n` (dependent on whether the server is Windows or *nix), it would only be visible to the user unless a `<pre>` tag was used, and if the `<pre>` tag was used then both `\n` and `\r\n` will be substituted with a single new line (at least on my Chrome 18). Still, you're right, you might as well use `PHP_EOL`, but just remember that it won't make any difference in the case of output.

Comment: absolutly. i'm always using (and advertising) PHP_EOL just because then you don't have to think about it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`extract`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function on $array_data to get variables.

```
$array_data = json_decode($json_data_string); 
extract($array_data); 
echo $index; 
echo $date;
```

Comment: Cool, how do i go about that?

Comment: i've added example to my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_string = $_POST['hidden_event'];
$array = json_decode ( $json_data_string);

extract ($array);

echo $date;
echo $title;
```

Comment: hmm that doesnt appear to work. Infact, i cannot echo out $array after it's been through json_decode?

Comment: No, but. even if i do: echo $array_data with what i have uptop in the question it doesnt work :s

Answer (score 0):

Try `var_dump` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), that will give you idea how `$array_data` is structured. If you do this

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array_data);
echo '</pre>';
```

you get even prettier dump. From there it's farily easy to see how to `echo` variables.

Comment: When i do that. I just get NULL

Comment: That means your JSONRequest is not sending anything, or parameter is not named as you mention there (`hidden_event`). It's tricky to sort out what happens in JSON requests, try var_dumping  whole `$_POST` (and maybe also `$_GET`). Are you sure that you are using JSON `POST` method, and not `GET`? If you have firefox, try using firebug, that gives you idea what happens with these "hidden" JSON requests.

Comment: from the manual : "NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit." you should try to var_dump($json_data_string); to see if it's well formated

Comment: TBH I didnt checked how `json_decode` behaves, and now thinking if $_POST['hidden_event'] would not exists you would find your problem earlier, so I stand corrected. Try what mathroc suggested, and you probably find your problem there. When ever I cannot use normal debug tools, I find `var_dump` very easy way to see what is going on.